# "Unable to resolve symbol" error in Clojure program

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, clojure

When I paste this code into a REPL, it works fine:

```
(use 'clojure.contrib.seq-utils)
(defn- random-letter [] (char (+ (rand-int 26) 97)))
(defn- random-digit [] (rand-int 10))
(defn- random-password
  "Returns an 8-character password consisting of letters and digits as follows: aa1aa1aa"
  []
  (let [password (interpose '((random-digit)) (repeat 3 (repeat 2 '(random-letter))))]
    (apply str (flatten (map (fn [coll] (map eval coll)) password)))))
```

Now, I have this code with `:gen-class :implements [my.ServiceInterface]` and a function prefixed with `-` to implement the interface. I unit-test with Maven/Groovy/TestNG. Everything works fine with several other interfaces/Clojure implementations, but in this particular case, I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: random-letter in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:32)
```

I can't figure out why. The only thing I can tell is different in this function from all the other functions, is that this is the only place where I use quoting, i.e. `'((random-digit))` and `'(random-letter)`. EDIT: also, this is the only place where I use `eval`.

I tried defining the functions as "non-private" (`defn` instead of `defn-`). I also tried a `(declare random-digit random-letter)` at the top. Neither of these solves the problem.

On a side note, if you have a suggestion for a better way to implement the `random-password` function, I am all ears. But I'd still like to know why I am getting this error and how to get this to work.

### Edit

Here is the complete code.

```
(ns fred.hp2010.service.ClojurePoolerService
  (:gen-class :implements [fred.hp2010.service.PoolerService])
  (:use [clojure.contrib.seq-utils :only (flatten)]))

(def dao (fred.hp2010.persistence.Repository/getDao))

(declare find-by is-taken random-password)

(defn -addPooler [this pooler] (. dao insert "POOLER" pooler))
(defn -getPoolers [this] (. dao list "poolers"))
(defn -isEmailTaken [this email] (is-taken {"email" email}))
(defn -isUsernameTaken [this username] (is-taken {"username" username}))
(defn -login [this email password] (. dao findSingle "POOLER" {"email" email "password" password}))

(defn -changePassword [this email new-password]
  (let [updated-pooler (assoc (into {} (find-by {"email" email})) "password" new-password)]
    (. dao update "POOLER" "POOLER_ID" updated-pooler)))

(defn -resetPassword [this email]
  (let [new-password (random-password)]
    (-changePassword this email new-password)
    new-password))

(defn- find-by [params] (. dao findSingle "POOLER" params))
(defn- is-taken [params] (not (nil? (find-by params))))

(defn- random-letter [] (char (+ (rand-int 26) 97)))
(defn- random-digit [] (rand-int 10))
(defn- random-password
  "Returns an 8-character password consisting of letters and digits as follows: aa1aa1aa"
  []
  (let [password (interpose '((random-digit)) (repeat 3 (repeat 2 '(random-letter))))]
    (apply str (flatten (map (fn [coll] (map eval coll)) password)))))
```

Comment: I dunno but Clojure, but in Scheme using eval requires some environment, and the error you are getting is what I would expect in Scheme. But alas, I dont know Clojure, so I cant help, but perhaps this will put you on the correct path. :)

Comment: Hm, you're probably right. This is also the only place that I use "eval". But then why does it work in the REPL and not when executing the unit test?

Comment: @leppie: so how would you fix this in Scheme? :-)

Comment: I've added another possible solution, hope you like it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why you're having problems compiling this with `:gen-class` but I wouldn't be surprised if `eval` had something to do with it.  `eval` is usually a bad idea.  One thing to try (completely untested) is to use `` ` `` (backquote) instead of `'` (quote) so that your symbols are namespace-qualified.  Don't know if that'd help or not.

Probably better to get rid of `eval` though.  If you turn your random-character functions into infinite lazy seqs via `repeatedly` you can do it this way:

```
(defn- random-letter [] (repeatedly #(char (+ (rand-int 26) 97))))
(defn- random-digit  [] (repeatedly #(rand-int 10)))
(defn- random-password
  "Returns an 8-character password consisting of letters and digits as follows: aa1aa1aa"
  []
  (apply str
         (mapcat (fn [[n f]] (take n (f)))
                 [[2 random-letter]
                  [1 random-digit]
                  [2 random-letter]
                  [1 random-digit]
                  [2 random-letter]])))
```

Comment: Thanks, <code>`<code> does fix the problem, after making the functions public with <code>defn</code>. Brian, is there anything you _don't_ know about Clojure? ;-)

Your point about eval being a bad idea is well taken, though. I'm trying to figure out a more elegant solution. I do like the idea of have 3 pairs of letters and interposing the digits within them, instead of the 2-1-2-1-2 solution.

Comment: "repeatedly" is what I was missing. How about this? <code>(apply str (take 8 (flatten (repeatedly #(list (random-letter) (random-letter) (random-digit))))))</code>

Comment: Yeah that's another good way.  It reminds me of `cycle`, I'll make an edit.  Anything that works is probably fine unless you're generating a billion passwords and need it to be fast.

Answer (score 3):

In the top handful of lines, I'm having a bit of trouble following the syntax. In particular, why all the quotes in line 7? Delayed evaluation of all those expressions is probably not helping you. I would guess that the quoted `'(random-letter)` is spoiling your fun.

You can probably write simpler code while eschewing `eval`. I'm going to go try it in the REPL, I hope to be back soon with an improved version.

**EDIT:**

OK, this works:

```
(apply str (interpose (random-digit) (repeat 3 (apply str (repeat 2 (random-letter))))))
```

...and it doesn't need anything from `clojure.contrib` :)

The `str` function will mung any arguments together into a string. If the arguments are in a list, you smuggle `str` inside the list by using `apply`.

As you said, Clojure is cool!

**EDIT:**

Here's a function that generates a random string of alphas and numerics in accordance with a String specification:

```
(apply str (map (fn [c] (if (= c \a) (random-letter) (random-digit))) "aanaanaa")))
```

It deviates a little bit from your spec but I think it's pretty cool.

Comment: Thanks, but your function uses the same letter and the same digit, as in gg4gg4gg. I know my comment says aa1aa1aa, but that's to show the placement of the letters and digits. I still want them to be different :) As in xy5ma8fr.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering if that was intentional! :) But I think I have a fix for that too. BRB.

Comment: How about this? (apply str (take 8 (flatten (repeatedly #(list (random-letter) (random-letter) (random-digit))))))

Comment: Well, it looks like the best of our suggestions are coalescing.